# Simple delegate method does not work

Tags: ios, delegates, ios4

Some help would be appreciated.

I have this simple project for testing purposes:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10101053/testDelegate.zip

I would like to pass a NSString in a delegate method but with this code does not work.

testDelegateViewController.h

```
@protocol testDelegateViewControllerDelegate; 


@interface testDelegateViewController : UIViewController {


id<testDelegateViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

IBOutlet UIButton *button;

}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<testDelegateViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button;

- (void)pass;

@end

@protocol testDelegateViewControllerDelegate

- (void)passSomeToDelegate:(NSString *)some;

@end
```

testDelegateVewController.m

```
#import "testDelegateViewController.h"

@implementation testDelegateViewController
@synthesize delegate, button;


- (void)pass
{
    NSLog(@"Button Pressed");
    [self.delegate passSomeToDelegate:@"some"];
}

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(pass) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

//rest of code
```

AppDelegate.h

```
#import "testDelegateViewController.h"

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, testDelegateViewControllerDelegate> {

}
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate


@synthesize window=_window;

@synthesize viewController=_viewController;

#pragma mark Delegate Method

- (void)passSomeToDelegate:(NSString *)some
{
    NSLog(@"%@", some);
}

//rest of code
```

But in my console nothing is printed when button is tapped.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to set your delegate. You can set the delegate in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{   
    self.viewController.delegate = self;

    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

I added `self.viewController.delegate = self;` to set the delegate.

Comment: this is helpful for beginner like me.